During the swap, a sufficient number of tokens did not arrive
Сan anyone explain to me where my tokens disappeared?https://solscan.io/tx/5Lg7n4KQVwFQpDgNj9czWa6mSdhHpjR7yXov8uwVSiicWzvTV1FRKv6J1xHPJiJ9bGj5V6EBy2dijNa5Uiv2gmbW?__cf_chl_rt_tk=yEkmeGAv9DQtdvL3F.2fcWEcOCgIaBPUkWXISMBxnV0-1733662522-1.0.1.1-7.cJF0JGfbhKQnbcrNjqOhNBb3qFv1WXOKwFkTsUIAQ

675.81 murph arrived, 13,516.20 murph should have arrived
